# Is there a way to dynamically add fields to a tree view in Odoo 11?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-view

I need to show each individual currency in the analytic account's "Costs & Revenues" lines, I would need to dynamically add columns for the different currencies each invoice has and show the total below (mimicking the behavior of the 'Amount' column that's already there), is there a way to do this or a workaround with a similar result?

The analytic account lines already store the amount in the original currency as well as the converted one to the company currency.

I want to avoid going mad by adding a field for each currency by hand.

Here's an example.

[image: example]

Comment: The columns are static on a tree view. Yo may create one single computed field "Amount", the returned value should be a string with all the values concatenated. The drawback of this is that you cannot show the total sum at the bottom.

Comment: I was thinking, maybe there could be a way to "trick" the frontend by sending more columns computed by hand mixed with the database values?

Comment: I do not think there is an easy way to achieve that. You can also create multiple tree views and show one or another depending on the columns you want to show, but you would need to create all the combinations. Actually I would show all the possible columns and if there is no value for the current row the space is left empty

Comment: Well, thanks, for now I'll be adding columns with the currencies as they are needed, maybe setting the unused ones with the invisible attribute.

Comment: Well, and if you want to make some experiment you can try this: before showing the tree view you can call an `ir.actions.server` and modify the view (`ir.ui.view`) by python code. Then you can return the `ir.action.window` in order to show the view already updated. That may work, but you would need to change all the references to that tree view and col the `ir.action.server` first. Tell me something if you try it, or if you do not understand what I am talking about hahah

Comment: You have all kind of [actions here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/actions.html)

Comment: Hi, you should search about **fields_view_get** method, with this method you can make dynamic views.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fields_view_get` method to update the view dynamically from python code (before the view is rendered). This is just an example that I found in Odoo:

```
@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = super(MailThread, self).fields_view_get(
        view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu
    )
    if view_type == 'form':
        doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
        for node in doc.xpath("//field[@name='message_ids']"):
            # the 'Log a note' button is employee only
            options = safe_eval(node.get('options', '{}'))
            is_employee = self.env.user.has_group('base.group_user')
            options['display_log_button'] = is_employee
            # save options on the node
            node.set('options', repr(options))
        res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc, encoding='unicode')
    return res
```

Place it in your model. Look for the column field with `doc.xpath` and update it with `node.set`

Actually is what Juan Salcedo said in his comment